# Change the default behaviour of drive icons in windows explorer?

Tags: windows-xp

In Microsoft Windows XP, is there a way to change default behavior of drive icons in explorer?
I know that autorun can be turned off for the removable drives, but can we also do the same for the fixed drives?

Comment: What do you call "default behavior", for a fixed drive ? The way it reacts on the double click ?

Comment: Yes, I want to change what it does on "double click".

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are referring to CD and DVD drives, right?  If things are happening automatically whenever you access a hard drive, it sounds like you have a virus of some sort.  There is no way within Windows to change the default doubleclick behavior of mapped hard drives.

From My Computer, rightclick on the drive to modify and open it's Properties.  If there is an AutoPlay tab, you can change the default action by choosing one from the list (including an option to "Take no action") or to have it prompt you for what you want to do every time the drive is accessed.

Comment: No, I was referring to the fixed drives icons (the hard disk partitions) not the removable drives.

Comment: On doubleclick, those will always open the root of the drive in Windows Explorer.  There isn't anything within Windows that you can do to change this.

It is possible that a third-party app may exist, but I don't know of one offhand.

Comment: Isn't there any way to stop Windows from executing autorun.inf on double click?

Comment: Permanent hard drives shouldn't have any autorun options.

Answer (score 0):

You get the autorun dialogue for fixed drives? Sounds like some virus behavior.

You can check if there is a *autorun.inf* in the drive's root and delete it.